# How do I send JSON but expect plain-text in response with AJAX / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

In the following script, I post data in JSON format to the server, but the response is sent back in plain-text.

```
    var regCredentials = {

        "username": creds.username,
        "password": creds.password,
        "fname": creds.fname,
        "lname": creds.lname

    };

    request = $.ajax({

        url: "internet.com/register",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: regCredentials,
        dataType: "json";

        request.always(function (data) {

                console.log("Response: " + data);
                postResponse(data);

        };

    });
```

Because the function expects JSON back, a `"` is appended to the returned data. It's probably parsed too, which doesn't throw an error for some reason.

**How can I write a JQuery AJAX Post that accepts a response in plaintext format?**

Edit:

My confusion I realize, is that I thought `data` determined the outgoing and incoming expected format rather than just incoming. Well that doesn't make much sense does it? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: change `dataType` to "text" if you are wanting to get back text

Comment: @PatrickEvans But I need to send JSON.

Comment: If you are getting an appended `"` in your response then you need to check your server side code. the `dataType` option has no effect on the data being sent just tells jQuery how to handle the incoming response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dataType` parameter is used to set the expected response type. In your case, set it to `text`. This does not affect the information which is sent in any way. As you are sending a POST request, the information will be placed in the requests' header. If it was a GET, it would be serialised to a string and appended to the URL in the querystring.

Your syntax around the handler function was a little off too. Try this:

```
var regCredentials = {
    "username": creds.username,
    "password": creds.password,
    "fname": creds.fname,
    "lname": creds.lname
};

request = $.ajax({
    url: "internet.com/register",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: regCredentials,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Response: " + data);
        postResponse(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I see. Now it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for that syntax tip also.